# How to 'walk' the line between (0,0) and (sin(45),sin(45))

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I need to find different values along the line between (0,0) and (.707,.707)
what is the correct way to do this using trig?

I know that any number mirrored with itself is on this line (.4,.4), but clearly my trig isn't up to snuff to do this with sin and radians

Answer (score 1):

In general, given two points $A$ and $B$, you can parametrize the line passing through the points by $$X(t) = A + t(B-A), \quad t \in \Bbb R.$$
If you only want the line segment, consider only values $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Do notice that $X(0) = A$ and $X(1) = B$. Your problem has nothing to do with trigonometry.